# Can I have multiple slice layouts in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, slices

Can I have multiple slice layouts in Photoshop?

I want to have multiple slice layouts and switch between them. Is it possible in Photoshop?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple slice layouts in photoshop"? -- At first I thought I knew what you meant ( using slice tool to cut layout into pieces ), but then you mentioned that you want to switch between them. I'm thinking that you basically want to have multiple versions of the same layout within one document and switch between them easily, is that so?

Comment: Yes, I want to have several sets of slices in one document.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

You can save slices in history state snapshots. If you use the history panel you can toggle between these states to access your different slices. As shown I moved the rectangle although it isn't necessary to change anything other than the slices.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What I do is select a slice or select multiple slices, right click > send to back or bring to front. To be honest, it had not occurred to me to use snapshots. If I tweak the content of a layer later on, do I have to change it in each snapshot?

Comment: The snapshot doesn't ever change I would think of it as a saved state or point in time. If you manipulated the content it would have no effect on the saved snapshot you'd have to create a new one.

Comment: I've been looking for "Layered" slices for a long time, but this workaround works extremely well. It even remembers which layers I have visible at a given time, which is something I had to manually do often when slicing elements which needed a background VS transparent. This also solves the issue with overlapping slices (ie: When an inner slices results the outer slice being exported with auto-generated "clipped" images). Pain-in-the-ass be gone! :)